# comparacion entre elementos del arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

```
public void VentaMayor(JLabel label){

    for(Franquicia f : arrFran){
        if(f.getVentAnuales()>f.ventAnuales){

        Object []arrObj = new Object[2];

        arrObj[0] = f.getNumFranquicia();
        arrObj[1] = f.getVentAnuales();


    }
```

Quisiera obtener el mayor y mostarlo en un jlabel, ya he buscado por todas partes y no he encontrado solución.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer un for para recorrer todo el arraylist y ver cual es el mayor. Ejemplo:

```
for (int x=1;x<listaNumeros.length;x++)
     {...}
```

Luego hacer uso de una variable auxiliar y comparar, guardando la posicion en otra variable.

```
if (listaNumeros[x]>auxmayor){
   auxmayor = listaNumeros[x];
   posicion= x;
}
```